# Regex search and grep everything between the second occurrence of first keyword and second keyword in a string - Python

Tags: python, regex, string

```
example_string = 'Hello A Bye, Hello B Ciao."
```

Wanted: `"B"`

What I want to use: `re.search()`

Normal approach:

```
res = re.search(r'Hello(.*?)Ciao', example_string)
```

But that approach would output: `"A Bye, Hello B"`.

Is there a way to tell the program to take the second occurrence of the first keyword. So in this case it would search for the second occurrence of the word "Hello" in the string and take this one as first keyword in `res`.

So that way it would simply output: `"B"`.

Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `re.findall` here to find all matches, and then access the second match:

```py
example_string = "Hello A Bye, Hello B Ciao."
matches = re.findall(r'\bHello (\w+)', example_string)
print(matches[1])  # B
```

Answer (score 0):

using of `re.findall` could work, findall() is probably the single most powerful function in the re module. Above we used re.search() to find the first match for a pattern. findall() finds *all* the matches and returns them as a list of strings, with each string representing one match.

Example: -

```
text = "He was carefully disguised but captured quickly by police."
>>> re.findall(r"\w+ly", text)
>>> ['carefully', 'quickly']
```